# PyODBC - Failing to Commit to SQL Server even with Connection.Commit AND Set NO COUNT ON

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, pyodbc

What I'm trying to do is simple. Insert into a SQL Server table that has an identity column. INSERT ONLY ONE RECORD into the table and after the insert get the newly auto incremented IDENTITY value using `@@IDENTITY`. or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableNameHere
(
  Column1 INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  Column2 INT
)
```

Here's my simple SQL code I'm trying to run:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO dbo.TableNameHere
(Column2) 
VALUES(100);

SELECT  @@IDENTITY As TheIDINeed;
```

I'm trying to run the above code through Pyodbc.

The problem is that the script runs fine, but no record shows up in the table dbo.TableNameHere, but the identity value gets incremented and returned via the @@IDENTITY. In essence, it feels like pyodbc is somehow inserting and then rolling back the first batch i.e., the insert statement and is returning the incremented @@IDENTITY accurately, even though it never committed it to the db.

I have tried wrapping my first batch i.e., the insert in a BEGIN TRAN AND COMMIT, but nothing changed. I even tried auto_commit = true in the connection string. I have been on/at it for a while. All/any help is much appreciated!

Here's the py code:

```
self.connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+self.server+';DATABASE='+self.database+';ENCRYPT=No;UID='+self.username+';PWD='+ self.password)

 self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
 
 self.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
 rtn = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
 print (rtn)
```

I also tried this separately, with no difference in the result:

```
self.cursor.execute(sql_statement)
self.connection.commit()
```

If I remove the `SELECT @@IDENTITY`, the insert runs smoothly. But I won't know the ID value inserted. I know I can easily code a workaround using a different query and get the max, but I do not want to go the route in case of concurrent sessions. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have also tried the SQL Native Client Driver, then tried the ODBC with auto_commit = True and also False, I have wrapped my SQL code in TRAN COMMITs, tried the connection string with and without the encrypt option and all the combinations thereof! At this point the options I have left with is to run a trace like one of the replies suggested below. But from the behavior, I'm fairly confident that its a rollback that's happening here!

Also, please ignore the self. references above, cos I have this in a class method.

Comment: Have you tried `INSERT INTO dbo.TableNameHere (Column2) OUTPUT inserted.Column1 VALUES(100);`? Ref: [INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql)

Comment: it sounds like you have wrong auto commit setting, so stuff is getting rollbacked. Also, don't use @@Identity, SCOPE_IDENTITY() is your friend

Comment: also, please just put the whole code there, not some piecemeal

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, thank you for your reply, I did try that too, but its the same result. Still stuck!

Comment: @siggemannen, will paste the code shortly

Comment: @siggemannen, could you expound on your comment about the "wrong auto commit setting"? (while I get back to my computer to post the code)....as I have mentioned in my description above in the problem statement, I have tried the connection string both with AND without the auto_commit = true. And I have even tried wrapping my first SQL statement in a transaction and committing it in SQL.

Comment: How are you checking whether the insert happened? And maybe set up a SQL Server trace to see what commands are actually being executed.

Comment: @Charlieface, thank u for your reply....the fact that every time I run it, although the table does not show the inserted record, the return value is accurate. So right now, my table only has a max val of 10 for Column1 (cos of the manual inserts I have performed on it through SQL Server), And I have run my Py script 11 times since. And the latest return value now is showing 21 and when I manually insert into the table on SQL Server now, the ID is starting at 22. Which tells me that INSERT has been getting rolled back every time when Py script is executed, so the Identity value is accurate

Comment: But the insert is getting rolled back. So right now the values in Column1 are: 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 22

Comment: well, every driver has different ways of specifying auto commit, i'm guessing from your description is that you didn't specify it correctly. Some drivers default to commit after every statement, some don't. if you post the whole code, it should be easier to see what the problem is

Comment: @siggemannen, gotcha!....posting the code now in 5 mins, need to lint and filter it a little, but will do it now. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Just posted the code.

Comment: did you manage to figure this out? I'm having the same issue and worse: it's only on 2 out of 6 tables. the other 4 are inserting as normal.